# DocumentDB connection string

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Azure application settings (for azure function) has a option for a DocumentDB connection string

[image]

Anyone have any idea how this should be populated/formatted?

i currently use:

```
var documentDbEndpointUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbEndpointUri"]);
            var documentDbAuthKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbAuthKey"];
            return new DocumentClient(documentDbEndpointUri, documentDbAuthKey);
```

Although I'd like to switch to a single value connection string.

Comment: Can you try something like `AccountEndpoint=https://accountname.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=accountkey==;`?

Comment: So I looked around and it seems even if you provide connection string like this, it won't be of any help to you as `DocumentClient` does not have an overload that takes connection string. Also, there's no parser method in the library. Closest I could find was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683369/documentdb-net-client-using-connection-string.

Answer (score 26):

Try `AccountEndpoint=https://accountname.documents.azure.com:443/‌​;AccountKey=accountk‌​ey==;Database=database`

Comment: The OP's issue isn't with finding the connection string. It's with using it as a parameter.

Comment: @hseddin  Find this as very useful when I'm trying to find the connection string which is needed for Migration Tool. Every documentation just error-prone and not complete.

Comment: For me Migration Tool gives an error when having `/` at the end of `https://accountname.documents.azure.com:443/‌​`. So use `https://accountname.documents.azure.com:443` instead

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as @Gaurav Mantri said in comment, currently `DocumentClient` does not have constructor overloads using connection string, you cannot directly use a connection string to create an instance of DocumentClient even if you provide/add connection string for DocumentDB in Azure application settings.

[image]

Note: here is [a feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/17777323-connection-string) for this issue, if you have same feature request, you can vote for it.

Secondly, If you’d like to access the DocumentDB service via `DocumentClient`, you can add both `DocumentDbEndpointUri` and `DocumentDbAuthKey` in App settings, and then read them in function code.

```
var serviceEndpoint = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbEndpointUri"];
var authKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbAuthKey"];

//or
//var serviceEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DocumentDbEndpointUri");
//var authKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DocumentDbAuthKey");
```

Comment: I wrote a helper that can create a DocumentClient off connection string here https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/203.  However, if you set the connection string dropdown to Document DB, it does not replace the connection string in the web.config file.  You must leave it Custom for it to work.  Not sure what that dropdown is doing to break things.