# Azure Function DocumentClient Binding

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to upgrade my DocumentDB nuget package from 1.13 to 1.18

I am facing issue while upgrading my azure function which is having a DocumentClient binding.

In DocumentDB 1.13 the binding sections does not take :{Id} as an binding parameter and was creating the DocumentClient object perfectly . Whereas the DocumentDB 1.18 needs {Id} as an binding parameter [ Which i dont want , as I want to iterate through entire documents in the collection ]

my host.json binding before 1.18 was

```
{
 "frameworks": {
 "net46": {
 "dependencies": {
 "Dynamitey": "1.0.2",
 "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB": "1.13.0",
 "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB": "1.0.0"
}
 }
}
```

my local.settings.json had only

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
 "AzureWebJobsStorage": " 
 DefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxxxx/xxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
 "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
 "AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString": 
 "AccountEndpoint=xxxxx/;AccountKey=xxxx==;",
 }
}
```

and my azure function looks like

```
 [FunctionName("DeleteAVFeedAuditData")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0/1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,  [DocumentDB]DocumentClient client,
    TraceWriter log)
{

    var c = client;
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    var value=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AVAuditFlushAfterDays"];

    var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("AVFeedAudit", "AuditRecords");
    //var documents = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri,"Select * from c where c.EndedAt");

    //foreach (Document d in documents)
    //{
    //    await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(d.SelfLink);
    //}

}
```

}

Now when running the azure function with updated package of documentDB 1.18 it says to bind the {Id} which will give only the single document with the specified id . Whereas my requirment is same as the previous version of DocumentDB 1.13.

Please tell how can i get the entire documents binded with my DocumentClient with the new updated package.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I checked this issue and reproduced this issue as follows:

[image]

> Please tell how can i get the entire documents binded with my DocumentClient with the new updated package.

Based on your scenario, I would recommend you construct the `DocumentClient` by yourself instead of using the binding to `DocumentClient` for a workaround to achieve your purpose.

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://<your-account-name>.documents.azure.com:443/"), "<your-account-key>");
```

And you could configure the `serviceEndpoint` and `accountKey` under your `local.settings.json` file just as the app setting `AzureWebJobsStorage`. Then you could use the following code for retrieving your setting value:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your-appsetting-key"];
```

Moreover, here is a [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683369/documentdb-net-client-using-connection-string) about constructing the `DocumentClient` from the connection string, you could refer to it.

**UPDATE:**

For 1.18, the following code could work as expected:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, [DocumentDB("brucedb01", "brucecoll01",ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString")] IEnumerable<dynamic> documents, TraceWriter log)
{
    foreach (JObject doc in documents)
    {
        //doc.SelectToken("_self").Value<string>();
        log.Info(doc.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bruce , As the azure function allows us to bind the documentclient directly so would not like to create the documentclient object explicitly . In v. 1.13 of documentDB it works fine with the binding , but in 1.18 its failing as asking me to bind a single document with the id configured in the settings.  My requirement is to bind the documentclient without Id.

Comment: I updated my answer for some research, you could refer to it. Moreover, I assumed that there be a bug, you could add your issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues).